# How to ignore multiple JUnit Test Classes?

Tags: java, maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm trying to execute some test cases in an very big applications. There are 100s of error test cases and some of them

- requires specific property files which won't be available in development environment.
- are outdated, but can't be simply removed

Is there anyway in which I can provide an XML or any other input which can list all the test classes to ignore?

I'm using **maven** with **surefire** plugin for executing test cases.

**PS**

I'm aware of `@ignore` annotation which can be used to ignore test cases or test classes. I don't want to use this because it requires changing each class which I want to ignore.

What I want is a single configuration file where I can mention all the classes to ignore.

Comment: Is there any reason that you can't use the include/exclude section in maven?
https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html

Comment: Well. I can use this. I was not aware of this.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 options:

1.To skip running the tests for a particular project, you can set skipTests to true.

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <skipTests>true</skipTests>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

2) Also you can skip the tests via command line by executing the following command:

```
mvn install -DskipTests
```

Comment: Please use uptodate information https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/ (3.0.0-M4 in the meantime...)

Answer (score 0):

You can potentially create a TestSuite that includes all the tests you *do* want to run, and then specify to Maven that it should use that particular Test Suite with:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>TestSuite.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

with TestSuite.java being the name of the suite you wish to run.
You could potentially have two and just switch that setting in your `pom.xml`when you wish to target only certain classes. 
This setting affects what tests are executed when you run `mvn test`.